# downloaded file supposed to be .png

Tags: java, samba

i dont know whats wrong with my code, i try to download png from server with sambautil

```
if (!path.equals("")) {
    SambaUtil su = new SambaUtil();
    byte[] data = su.openfile(path);
    log.info(path);
    ByteArrayInputStream inStream =  new ByteArrayInputStream(su.openfile(path));
    PrintWriter outStream1  = resp.getWriter();
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = inStream.read()) != -1) {
        outStream1.write(bytes);
    }

    inStream.close();
    outStream1.close();

}
```

the connection is right, but output data seems wrong

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv8fa.png)

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: why do you open twice? `su.openfile(path);`

Comment: Do tou see the letters JFIF at the begging of the stream?  That's because the image file you downloaded is a JPEG, not a PNG.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are taking the bytes that make up the .PNG file and printing it out instead of saving it as a file which is what I think you want to do.

Instead of

```
PrintWriter outStream1  = resp.getWriter();
```

Replace with this

```
OutputStream outStream1 = new FileOutputStream("somefile.png");
```

Then open the 'somefile.png' and you should be able to see the image that you downloaded via Samba